# For some linear transformation T, if $T(u_0)=w$ and $T(v)=0$ then $T(u)=w$ if and only if $u=u_0+v$ proof inquiry

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : V → W$ be a linear transformation. Let $w ∈ W$ and let $u_0 ∈ V$ satisfy
$$T(u_0) = w$$

Show that $u ∈ V$ is a solution of the equation
$T(u) = w$ if and only if $u = u_0 + v$, where $T(v) = 0$

---

The proof of this consists of two parts:

1)Prove that $T(u)=T(u_0+v)=T(u_0)+T(v)=w+0=w$

2)Prove that all $u$ that satisfy $T(u)=w$ are in the form $u=u_0+v$

How should I go about proving the second part?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To show $2)$, you need to show that if $u\in V$ is such that $T(u) = w$, then we must have $u = u_0 + \color{magenta}{v}$ for some $v\in V$ with $T(v) = 0$. It thus suffices to show that $$\color{blue}{T(u-u_0) = 0}$$ (since $u = u_0 + \color{magenta}{(u-u_0)}$). Can you show the last equality?

Comment: Isnt it just T(u-u0)=T(u)-T(u0)=w-w=0=T(v). Thus u-u0=v and u=u0+v?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $T(u)=w=T(u_0)$, can you calculate $T(u-u_0)$?

Comment: Isnt it just T(u-u0)=T(u)-T(u0)=w-w=0=T(v). Thus u-u0=v and u=u0+v?

Comment: Yes, but it is equal to $v$ for *some* $v$ such that $T(v)=0$, not *any* $v$.